# Ajax request going out of range

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(function(){
var imgClass = $('.caruselWrap').find('img');  
imgClass.eq(1).addClass('pro');
var hasPro = $('.caruselWrap').find('img.pro');
var count = 3; // "position" of images, security for not breaking out
var imgLoaded = 3;
var flag = true;
var arr = [];

var ajax = function() {
    var url = 'gallery/img' + count + '.jpg';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {
            arr[imgLoaded] = '<img class="addedImg" src="' + url + '" />';
            $('.caruselWrap').append(arr[imgLoaded]);
            flag = true;

            $('.addedImg').click(function(){ 
                var img = $(this);
                check(img);

                console.log("count: " + count);
                console.log("images loaded: " + imgLoaded);
                console.log(flag);
            })

        }
    }
    request.send();
    imgLoaded++;
}

var change = function(string) {
    if((string == "left") && (count >= 3)) {
        hasPro.prev().addClass('pro').next().removeAttr('class');
    } else if (string == "right") {
        hasPro.next().addClass('pro').prev().removeAttr('class');
    }
}

var check = function(a){
    var add = imgClass.outerWidth(true);
    hasPro = $('.caruselWrap').find('img.pro');

    if(hasPro.index() > a.index()){
        if(count > 3) {
            --count;
            change("left");

            $('.caruselWrap').animate({
                left: '+=' + add,
            })
        }
    } else if(hasPro.index() < a.index()) {
        if(flag) {
            ++count;
            if(imgLoaded < count) {
                ajax();
            }
            change("right");            
            $('.caruselWrap').animate({
                left: '-=' + add,
            })
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Center image clicked! Full screen view");
    }
}

$('.caruselWrap img').click(function(){ 
    var img = $(this);
    check(img);

    console.log("count: " + count);
    console.log("images loaded: " + imgLoaded);

})

})
```

Hi, i need advice in modifying my code. Main assumption is that carousel has 3 images visible, center image always has class "pro". 
Main problem here is that with loading images via ajax i'm getting out of range with images avaible for gallery. It stops on next (non existing) element/img in folder.

[Click for preview](http://carousel.psmul.tk/)

Any advices would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "out of range"? Do you mean there's no more images to show?

Comment: $('.caruselWrap').append(arr[imgLoaded]); You are appending something without checking it if it's not empty.

Comment: @FabianLauer I mean if you go to link with preview you will see that if you click to the end of photos it will still animate "next element"  so i mean that animation is still doing even if there is no image.

Comment: @Mr.TK I changed my code to check if arr[imgLoaded] isn't undefined nor null but it's still not helping.

Comment: I think problem is that i need to check next element after loading to stop animation from executing. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Jquery, Then use jquery version of ajax. Take a look

```
     // get ajax request

     $.get('url',{param:value,param2:value},function(response){
         // do your stuff with response;
     }); 

     // post ajax request
     $.post('url',{param:value,param2:value},function(response){
         // do your stuff with response;
     }); 

   // another version
     $.ajax({
         url:'',
         method:'POST/GET',
         success: function(response){
                      // do your stuff with response;
        }
     });
```